# Managing currency type to edit Entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, currency

I'm working with an Expense entity containing *Price* information, for which I have chosen to split the amount (int) from the currency (string).

```
/**
 * @var integer
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="price_amount", type="integer")
 */
private $priceAmount;

/**
 * @var string
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(name="price_currency", type="string", length=10)
 */
private $priceCurrency;
```

I am using the MoneyBundle (through TBBC bundle) to have the **creation** form display the list of supported currencies and letting the user choose the correct one. After validation of the form, the price currency is stored as a string in the database.

```
         // ExpenseType.php
         [...]
         use Tbbc\MoneyBundle\Form\Type\CurrencyType;
         [...]
         $builder
            ->add('priceAmount', NumberType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Amount spent',
                'attr' => array(
                    'placeholder' => "Amount",
                    'autocomplete' => 'off'
            )))
            ->add('priceCurrency', CurrencyType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Currency'
            ))
```

I am trying to create another form type ExpenseEditType (extends the ExpenseType above) that will help the user **modify** the amount (amount itself + its currency); Obviously when I load the ExpenseEditType form symfony tries to create a CurrencyType from my doctrine entity, but it only finds a string (e.g. "CAD", "EUR", etc.) in the database.

```
    $form = $this->createForm(new ExpenseEditType(), $expense);
```

Exception raised:

> Expected argument of type "Currency", "string" given

My question is: how can I create the same kind of form than for the creation one, and ask symfony to display the same list of currency, selecting a default value with what it finds in my price.currency field?

I am thinking of 2 options (but I might be totally wrong):
- working with DataTransformer, but only beginning with Symfony, I really don't know anything about this kind of stuff
- having an extra Money field in my Expense entity that will store the amount+currency information in one single Money field, on top of my 2 separated fields (amount / currency); I would like to stick with these 2 separated fields for better querying possibility and lisibility in the database.

Thanks a lot for your help and advices!
Vincent

Comment: have a look here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

Comment: Follow the link from above about the DataTransformers - it's very straightforward and nothing to be nervous about.  You want to convert your string to Currency and the example given is essentially exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Heah and Jason suggestion, I went with DataTransformer solution and it's working well :) I based my code on the [official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html).

Find below the result:

**StringToCurrencyTransformer.php**

```
<?php

namespace VP\AccountsBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

// some uses

class StringToCurrencyTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface {

    private $manager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager) {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    /**
     * Transforms a String (currency_str) to a Currency
     * 
     * @param String|null $currency_str
     * @return Currency The Currency Object
     * @throws UnknownCurrencyException if Currency is not found
     */
    public function transform($currency_str) {
        if (null === $currency_str) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            $currency = new Currency($currency_str);
        } catch (UnknownCurrencyException $ex) {
            throw new TransformationFailedException(
            sprintf(
                    'The currency "%s" does not exist', $currency_str
            ));
        }
        return $currency;
    }

    /**
     * Transforms a Currency (currency) to a String
     * @param Currency $currency
     * @return String|null The ISO code of the currency
     * @throws TransformationFailedException if currency is not found
     */
    public function reverseTransform($currency) {
        // if no currency provided
        if (!$currency) {
            return;
        }
        $currency_str = $currency->getName();
        return $currency_str;
    }

}
```

**My new ExpenseEditType.php**

```
<?php

// some uses

class ExpenseEditType extends ExpenseType   {

    private $manager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $manager) {
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
        $builder->remove('submitnew')
                ->remove('priceCurrency')
                ->add('priceCurrency', CurrencyType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Devise',
                    'invalid_message' => 'Currency not found'
                ))
                ->add('submitnew', SubmitType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'Edit expense',
                    'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                    )
        ));
        $builder->get('priceCurrency')
                ->addModelTransformer(new StringToCurrencyTransformer($this->manager));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return 'vp_accountsbundle_expenseedit';
    }
```

**My service.yml:**

```
services:
    app.form.type.expenseedit:
        class: VP\AccountsBundle\Form\ExpenseEditType
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

My call from the controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(ExpenseEditType::class, $expense);
```

Thanks again folks!